# collate property to store a translated string in mysql?

Tags: mysql

My table has collate property`latin1_swedish_ci` by default, with this strings are stored normally but if any translated string needs to be stored in DB then  question marks are storing instead of plain text i.e., when i am storing other language string in Db we are seeing

```html
???????
```

.

Please suggest me the solution so that i can store any language string in DB.

Comment: Collation has **nothing** to do with *storing* data. If you inserted data into your database and then pulled it out, it means you are using a program that *displays* that data. The potential problems: the program inserting the data doesn't understand your strings **or** the program displaying the data doesn't understand your strings. Database and collation are not your problems. Btw. collation is a rule for ordering strings, it's basically something that tells MySQL that after letter `A` comes letter `B` etc. and it's used when you `order by`.

Comment: Thanks N.B. , what could be the pbm i'm using eclipselink persist method to store translated string to mysql, when i fetch data from DB i'm getting ?????...I'm able to translate each word successfully but when i'm storing i'm facing this issue...pls guide me to solve this pbm.

Comment: I don't know what "pbm" means.

Comment: Set the connection charset to `utf8` (MySQL query for that is `SET NAMES utf8`). Set the table's charset to `utf8`.

Comment: Can u please send me any example.....i'm having two columns in a table both columns should be set to utf8...How can i check my value, if it is changed to utf8 or not. I want u to alter existed table not to create again...